# If $U$ is a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n,n>2$ and $V$ is a closed subvariety of $U$, show that $U-V$ is connected

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

The question is taken from the notes by Joseph L.Taylor http://people.math.sfu.ca/~kya17/seminars/Taylor_Notes_On_Several_Complex_Variables.pdf 
problem 5.2. Since $D$ is already given to be closed, then $U - D$ is open in $U$ and it suffices to just show that $U - D$ is closed in $U$ as well.

I tried to use the fact from topology that a set is closed iff it contains all its limit points. Let $(\lambda_n)$ denote a sequence in $U - D$ converging to say $\lambda \in U$. We show that $\lambda \notin D$.

By the definition of a subvariety, we have for each $n$, a neighbourhood $W_{\lambda_n}$ of $\lambda_n$ such that $D\cap W_{\lambda_n}=V(S_n)$ for some subset $S_n \subset \mathcal{H}(W_{\lambda_n})$.  Unfortunately I am stuck here as I have very little clue on how to use the fact that $\lambda_n \notin D$ to my advantage.

Any help given would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $U\setminus V = \{x : x \in U, x \notin V\}$ or $U-V = \{x-y : x \in U, y \in V\}$?

Comment: The complement set. Sorry for the misleading notation

Comment: Then I guess some more hypotheses must be added, otherwise for $n = 1$ (in $\mathbb{C}$) take $U = \{ z : |z| < 1\}$ and $V = \{ z : |z| = 1/2\}$, or I am missing something?

Comment: The question is taken from the course in several complex variables so we naturally assume $n > 2 $.

Comment: @Hugo: Moreover, $V$ is a complex subvariety, not just an arbitrary closed subset. The main idea is that a complex subvariety has *real* codimension $\ge 2$. Think locally about what the complement of $\Bbb C$ in $\Bbb C^2$ looks like. Probably seeing path-connectivity is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

First suppose that $U$ is convex. Take two points $p,q \in U\backslash V$. Draw a (complex) line $L$ joining $p$ and $q$ then the functions defining $V$ restrict to holomorphic functions  on $L$ and their common zero set is $V\cap L$. Holomorphy implies that $V\cap L$ is discrete, otherwise $L\subset V$. From $U$ convex we get that $L\cap U$ is connected.

Naturally, the complement of a discrete set in a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is connected, hence path-connected and you can draw a contiuous path between $p$ and $q$ inside $L\cap U$.

For the general case you can draw a "complex polygonal" and do the same in each edge.